# exception 'Google_ServiceException' with message

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, google-api-php-client

I got the error like below.

```
exception 'Google_ServiceException' with message 'Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet%2Cstatus&uploadType=multipart: (401) Unauthorized' in D:\wamp\www\youtube\google-api-php-client\src\io\Google_REST.php:66 Stack trace: #0 D:\wamp\www\youtube\google-api-php-client\src\io\Google_REST.php(36): Google_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(Google_HttpRequest)) #1 D:\wamp\www\youtube\google-api-php-client\src\service\Google_ServiceResource.php(186): Google_REST::execute(Object(Google_HttpRequest)) #2 D:\wamp\www\youtube\google-api-php-client\src\contrib\Google_YouTubeService.php(887): Google_ServiceResource->__call('insert', Array) #3 D:\wamp\www\youtube\index.php(67): Google_VideosServiceResource->insert('snippet,status', Object(Google_Video), Array) #4 {main}
```

i want to make a script for upload a video on you tube. i am using http://www.dreu.info/blog/uploading-a-video-to-youtube-through-api-version-3-in-php/ this line of code. authentication and all works fine but not upload video.

Answer (score 0):

You should set your client id and secret in that code from your [devconsole](https://code.google.com/apis/console/). Also enable Data API v3 in that console too.

Comment: ya i already set setClientId, setClientSecret, setDeveloperKey etc. and also enable you tube api. 
this script works in some gmail account but some how not. So, whats reason behind that?